# Are there available fluids that can be used in place of blood to facilitate oxygen and carbon dioxide exchange during major surgery/trauma?

Tags: physiology, medicine, surgery

Are there any available fluid alternatives that can be used instead of blood replacement that adequately exchange oxygen and carbon dioxide?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question - - - are you asking if another fluid can be used in the airways to help exchange oxygen and carbon dioxide?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_substitute

Comment: No sir. I meant are there alternative IV fluid that can help to transport oxygen in the cardiovasular system in cases like major sugery where parallel blood infusion can't  meet up with the rate of blood loss. Thanks